# PineScript: Is it possible to scroll inside a table?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Sometimes the content of the table is larger than the table itself.

Is it possible to scroll the content of the table?

Or to use any other element instead of a table to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling is not supported.

You can try using a smaller text size. Change `text_size` argument of `table.cell()` to `size.small` for example.